# How mount many directories with the same name over the LAN on /Volumes?

Tags: finder, network, mount, folders

In Windows 10, through *Windows Explorer* is possible stablish a network connection for a remote directory and thanks to the `Map network drive` approach is possible keep that connection mapped with a *drive*, so if three machines has the same directory name - lets consider *documents* - so is possible get:

```
M:\documents
N:\documents
W:\documents
```

In Mac - *El Capitan* - through:

- `Finder` -> `Go` -> `Connect to Server`

Is possible do the connection with `smb://hostname/documents`

Therefore the `documents` remote directory is mounted on `/Volumes`

```
/Volumes
 documents
```

The problem is, what happen if other two machines have the same *documents* directory name? - Consider it how a mandatory policy of the company - How is mounted in `/Volumes`? How recognize each mounted remote directory within each machine in the LAN? I want rename the mounted directory through Finder, but is not possible.

I want have in MacOS in `/Volumes` the following structure:

```
/Volumes
 192.168.1.55
    documents
 192.168.1.56
    documents
 192.168.1.57
    documents
```

It to have the isolated paths available to be used on some bash-shell scripts. How accomplish this goal?

Comment: You could have just mounted two of them and looked at what the OS created in /Volumes, you know.  It suffixes a number.

Comment: @MarcWilson However that depends on the order you attach them which might not be the same each time - asking to be able to add something that can be controlled in the path is a good question (although asking it twice is not good)

Comment: Yes. I don't want depend about `XXX` and `XXX-1` - because there is no garanty about the sort/order and later can happen a disconnect and reconnection - so the automatic paths are useless - I want take explicit control about the names. The other question is more specific about command. Here is open to either Finder or Command. Or perhaps rename a mounted directory. The other is through the connection itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example script. This script is modeled after the actions take by the Finder application. To simplify this answer, little error checking takes place.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo mkdir -p "/Volumes/${1#*@}"
sudo chown $USER:staff "/Volumes/${1#*@}"
mount -t smbfs -o nodev,nosuid  "$1" "/Volumes/${1#*@}"
mount | grep -q "/Volumes/${1#*@}" && open "/Volumes/${1#*@}"
```

> Note: Since you require folders to be created inside the `/Volumes` folder, the user's password may be requested by the script.

If the script is saved to the file `connect`, then the synopsis would be the following.

```
connect //user[:password]@server/share
```

An example is given below.

```
./connect //davidanderson@192.168.1.55/documents
```

In this example, the mount point would be the following.

```
/Volumes/192.168.1.55/documents
```

To unmount, the synopsis would be the following.

```
diskutil unmount /Volumes/server/share
```

An example of the command to unmount is given below.

```
diskutil unmount /Volumes/192.168.1.55/documents
```

---

### Comment

While the above answer is designed to meet the requirements stated in the question, the answer is not very robust. If two or more users attempt to access the same share, then using the above answer will result in failure. Basically, the problem is more that one user can not use the same mount point at the same time. One way to avoid this problem would be to place the mount point in the `$HOME/Volumes` folder instead of the `/Volumes` folder. The new script given below is a modified version of the original script given above. This new script places the mount point in the `$HOME/Volumes` folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p "$HOME/Volumes/${1#*@}"
chmod 700 "$HOME/Volumes"
chmod +a "group:everyone deny delete" "$HOME/Volumes"
mount -t smbfs -o nodev,nosuid "$1" "$HOME/Volumes/${1#*@}"
mount | grep -q "$HOME/Volumes/${1#*@}" && open "$HOME/Volumes/${1#*@}"
```

Note: Since `/Volumes` folder is not used, the user's password will not be requested by the script.

If the script is saved to the file `connect`, then the synopsis would be the following.

```
connect //user[:password]@server/share
```

An example is given below.

```
./connect //davidanderson@192.168.1.55/documents
```

In this example, the mount point would be the following.

```
"$HOME/Volumes/192.168.1.55/documents"
```

To unmount, the synopsis would be the following.

```
diskutil unmount "$HOME/Volumes/server/share"
```

An example of the command to unmount is given below.

```
diskutil unmount "$HOME/Volumes/192.168.1.55/documents"
```

Comment: Does `-pm` work together? it is not correct, it only affects to the latest directory. In this case through `$3`

Comment: Well, `-pm700` is short for `-p -m 700`. If this is a problem for you, then I will just change my answer. I do intend for the command to only change the the latest (last) directory. I am not sure the `-m 700` is even needed. I only added this because apparently this is what the Finder and `diskutil mount` do.

Comment: About the `pm` It does not work as expected - pls see this post and the two answers and the comments of them - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786326/how-to-create-a-directory-and-give-permission-in-single-command - So I replaced `sudo mkdir -p -m 700 "/Volumes/$2/$3"` by `sudo mkdir -p "/Volumes/$2/$3"` and `sudo chmod -R 700 "/Volumes/$2/$3"`

Comment: After further investigation, I determined the default file modes should be use. Therefore, the `chmod` command and the `-m` option for the `mkdir` command are not needed. I updated my answer accordingly. This would also make the above comments irrelevant with respect to this answer.

Comment: Huge thanks for the valuable update - just being curious why `diskutil unmount` and not only `umount`?  like other _unix/linux_ distributions such as Ubuntu. BTW about share `/Volumes/something` to be shared among many users - for each user I created a new common group - `developer` - and with `chgrp` I changed the primary group `/Volumes/something`

Comment: Just being curious why did you change from `mount_smbfs` to `mount -t smbfs`? Are they equivalents or is there an important difference?

Comment: I was reading the man page for `mount_smbfs`, which states the following: *"**Note:** You should always use the system mount command and never call mount_smbfs directly."* Conversely, I was also reading the man page for `umount`, which states the following: *"**NOTES** Due to the complex and interwoven nature of Mac OS X, **umount** may fail often. It is recommended that diskutil(1) (as in, ``diskutil unmount /mnt'') be used instead."*

Answer (score 1):

The `mount` command lets you specify a mount_point:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs smb://hostname/documents /Volumes/documents-foo
```

Just change `documents-foo` to whatever you want it to be called, and note that that directory must already exist (create it with `sudo mkdir /Volumes/documents-foo` if it doesn't)

Comment: I tested this answer using El Capitan and the answer failed to work. What operating system did you use to test. Or, did you test?

Comment: It does not work - it arises `mount_nfs: can't resolve host: smb` and `mount_nfs: no usable addresses for host: smb`

Comment: I believe `mount` should have been `mount -t smbfs` or just `mount_smbfs` , but that is probably not the only problem.

Comment: The `sudo mount -t smbfs smb://hostname/documents /Volumes/documents-foo` command mounts, but the user can not access the share without using `sudo`. By removing the `sudo` and entering the `mount -t smbfs smb://hostname/documents /Volumes/documents-foo` command, the share mounts, but also allows user access without using `sudo`.

Comment: You're right, I left out `-t smbfs`. I meant to edit out the username and password from the command I tested with, and removed too much. I'll edit that in.