# When diskutil mount vs mount?

Tags: disk-utility, mount, folders

I know how to mount in Linux at `/mnt` through the `mount` command, the same command exists on macos too.

After to read the following tutorial:

- [Mount & Unmount Drives from the Command Line in Mac OS X](https://osxdaily.com/2013/05/13/mount-unmount-drives-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/)

It uses `diskutil mount` instead of `mount`. Why?

Now, according with this other post (the solution) works:

- [How mount many directories with the same name over the LAN on /Volumes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437082/how-mount-many-directories-with-the-same-name-over-the-lan-on-volumes)

It uses `mount -t smbfs` instead and not `diskutil mount -t smbfs` how perhaps would be expected.

Should I assume:

- if is used `mount` with `-t` is not necessary or not should be used `diskutil`?
- is mandatory use `diskutil mount` if `-t` is **not** required?

In `man mount` there is no mention of the `diskutil` term, all the contrary where in `man umount` (and mentioned in a comment in the answer/solution of the previous link)

```
NOTES 
Due to the complex and interwoven nature of Mac OS X, umount may fail often. 
It is recommended that diskutil(1) (as in, ``diskutil unmount /mnt'') be used instead.
```

There the indication is explicit and clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `diskutil` simplifies many tasks would otherwise require entering multiple commands. However, mounting a share from a remote server using SMB/CIFS protocol can not be accomplished using the `diskutil` command. In such a case, the `mount` command can be use.

> The `mount` verb associated with the `diskutil` command does not have a `-t` option.

Basically, some tasks will require using `diskutil`, other tasks can be accomplished with or without `diskutil`, and finally, there are tasks that `diskutil` can not do.

When possible, I would recommend using `diskutil` over `mount`. However, you are not required to do so when mount will also work.